# R: Looping over the list and applying the as variable

Tags: r

I wrapped up the caret functionality to use with different random splits (variable i) and currently stacked over the problem - I don't know how to loop over the methods. paste doesn't work for me.

```
methods <- c("svmLinear","svmRadial")

for (M in methods) {
    for (i in c(1:5)) {
    data_load(act_file = "act.txt",
        inact_file = "inact.txt")
    sets(Rand=i)
    mod_parms(k_folds=5)
    modeling_y_testing(method = M, metric='ROC',tuneLength=10)
    rm(list = ls())
    }
}
```

the error is following

```
object 'M' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) : Variable(s) `' constant. Cannot scale data.
Execution halted
```

I suppose I need to convert the variable in `methods` into some sort of a character that should be accepted to modeling_y_testing (a caret-based function), but I don't know. You help is very appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to `rm(list=ls())` ?

Comment: cleaning up memory, but that the main cause )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
`rm(list = ls())`
```

This function removes the variable `M`. So on the second iteration of the loop

```
`for(i in 1:5){`
```

we get the error

```
 object `M` not found
```